# Plone 4.2: How to start a new installed instance in the same server?

Tags: plone, instances

Plone 4.2.5 with ZEO

There is a running instance in /cms/plone4.  Today I install another instance in /opt/plone4.  When I start the instance in /opt/plone4 (plonectl start) after stopped the instance in /cms/plone4, I find that the running one is still the one in /cms/plone4 even after server reboot.

How can I start the new one?

Best regards.
Hugo

Comment: Are you picking up the right `plonectl` binary in your path, i.e. `/opt/plone4/bin/plonectl start`?

Comment: Yes, I did try to start it with full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"even after server reboot" may be the key clue to your problem. You've got some init routine that is starting /cms/plone4. There's a good chance that it's a monitoring routine that watches the Plone process and restarts it if it stops. An example of that kind of process monitor (and one that's very popular among Plone integrators) is supervisor.

So, track down the routine that's starting /cms/plone4 on system restart. Change its setup to exclude /cms/plone4 and replace it with the new one.

Comment: Can you tell me how to track down the routine in Debian6?

Comment: on linux you can use pstree to see which process has been started by which other process

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the port number in the buildout.cfg ?
By default plone is running on 8080, change one to another port.